# Slow BIOS bootup

Tags: windows-7, windows, motherboard, bios, hardware-failure

This is a new HP DV-7 laptop. When you turn it on SOMETIMES it will wait at 15 minutes on the press escape for menu and sometimes it will boot correctly.

IS this a hardware failure issue or is this a new for a BIOS update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sounds like a hardware problem -- i'd first try going into the bios, and reset it to default config. Save and reboot and see if the problem presists. It's possible that some setting is causing the hangup.

Also, often times, a failing harddrive or storage device (USB thumb drive, external hard drive, memory card, etc) can cause the POST process to hang while the BIOS attempts to enumerate all devices. Try unplugging any external devices if any are plugged in. Reboot and see what happens.

If your hard drive is starting to fail, it will cause the hung post process. if this is a new laptop, i'd send it in under warranty (after making a backup of everything! - they will likely just throw in a new drive).

Comment: Anyway to run a scan to check if a hardware device is going bad?

Comment: of course -- but it will depend on your machine if it has built-in diagnostics (a lot do now-a-days). usually to get to them, at the POST screen you would press one of the F keys, usually like F10, F11, F12, to launch diagnostics.

Comment: if your system does not have them built in, try out a diag cd like Hiren's bootcd. 

    http://www.hirensbootcd.org/files/Hirens.BootCD.15.2.zip

download, unzip and burn the .iso to cd, boot to this from your pc, choose the MSDOS tools, and go to hard drive utilities (or something to that effect), look for IBM/Hitachi DFT (Drive Fitness Tool), run the extended test,it will take a few hours probably depending on your drive size.